# How to iterate through dictionary shape .txt file to create DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, txt

I have .txt file with a dictionary inside, like (several rows):

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "title": "Greatest chess game",
            "created_time": "2020-02-17T16:51:44+0000"
         } 
             ]
}
```

I need to open this file and create df look alike:

```
     title                 created_time
0    Greatest chess game   2020-02-17T16:51:44+0000
....
```

When I open txt file:

```
output_file=open('data\\data_new.txt', 'w')
with open(output_file, 'r') as reader:
    print(reader.readline(5))
```

It treats as a:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

How could I convert it ?

Comment: Please post code you tried and your txt file is actually json

Comment: Edit your question and post **full** code

Comment: You are calling ``open`` twice – first on the path, then again on the already ``open``'d file. Remove one of the ``open`` calls.

Comment: if you shortened it like this: with open(open('data\\data_new.txt', 'w'), 'r') as reader: #code here# you’ll see that you tried to read opened file try to do
with open(r'data\data_new.txt', 'r') as reader: print(reader.readline(5))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are opening the file twice, once in read mode and once in write, not sure that's actually possible.

Anyway, as mentioned what you appear to have is JSON so use the json library to read the file.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('data_new.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as reader:
    json = json.load(reader )
    
df = pd.DataFrame(json['data'])

print(df)
```

Comment: Here I am getting: 

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1651223: character maps to <undefined>      

if adding:  encoding="utf8"

Then:

JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 66852 column 77 (char 3655872)

Comment: data_new.txt is from FB API query

Comment: I've edited the code, see if it works now.

Comment: Noup, 

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1651223: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Now ok !
https://jsonlint.com/ also helped me to find mistakes in json file

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use json lib to open your text file as json file, like:

```
import json

with open('data.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    #here you can make you dataframe
```